# Xcode 5 - новое приложение для iOS 6.1

Tags: xcode, ios

Здравствуйте.
Xcode 5 работает с приложениями для iOS 6.1, а вот создать новое приложение для iOS 6.1 не получается. Возможно ли это?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не возможно. Только в более старых версиях Xcode (например 4.6.3 - последняя перед пятой версией) но проекты собранные в них уже не верифицируются в Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно! Делаем так:
[link](http://vk.com/photo11311027_313634766) http://vk.com/photo11311027_313634766
а потом так:
[link](http://vk.com/photo11311027_313634781) http://vk.com/photo11311027_313634781
наслаждаемся кодингом,

Comment: а на кой это надо если через месяц почти у 90 процентов стоит новая версия системы?

Comment: далеко не у 90%. Допустим, половина владельцев iДевайсов, которых я знаю, не собираются пока переходить на iOS7. Кроме того, человек спросил, я ему ответил. Зачем и кому это нужно, вопрос не ко мне.